# URL rewrite php query strings

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have two urls doing some queries which I'm struggling to rewrite in the manner I want.

**First**

```
/shop/index.php?category=catslug
```

which I want to be

```
/shop/category
```

**Second**

```
/shop/index.php?product=slug
```

to

```
/shop/category/product
```

I have this currently:

```
RewriteRule ^shop/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ shop/index.php?category=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^shop/[A-Za-z-]+/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ shop/index.php?product=$1 [NC,L]
```

The problem is that one of the rules is ruining anything that starts with shop so that things like `shop/cart` doesn't work. I'm so confused. Is this possible?

Comment: Can't research the full answer now, but this is what `RewriteCond`  is for. See:   http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html    
also http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/modrewrite-tips-tricks/   for syntax and examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that for `shop/cart`, the `cart` part matches the `[A-Za-z0-9-]+` part of the first `RewriteRule`.  So it is rewritten to `shop/index.php?category=cart`.

The way to avoid this, hoping that you have a relatively small number of fixed URLs, is to have a `RewriteRule` before your 2 rules like

```
RewriteRule ^shop/(cart|this|that|other|thing) - [L]
RewriteRule ^shop/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ shop/index.php?category=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^shop/[A-Za-z-]+/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ shop/index.php?product=$1 [NC,L]
```

For requests matching one of the pipe-delimited strings (such as `cart`), `-` means don't change the request, and `[L]` means last (don't continue to the next rules).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. This does indeed work, although it causes a 404 when trying to reach those pages now. Would that have something to do with the later rules the remove the trailing .php extension?

Comment: Scrap that... I moved the rule below the rule that removes the .php extension and it works perfectly.